# Magento preserve form/grid input values on error/exception at server side

Tags: forms, magento, grid

While submitting forms and grids in Magento, if some error/exception comes then how all user inputs can be preserved and reproduce same form so that user can easily correct the error and resubmit the form

Answer (score 2):

The Grid has a method for such:

`setSaveParametersInSession()`

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html#setSaveParametersInSession

As for forms take a look at:

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php

`restoreData()` I believe is what your looking for.

http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Customer/Mage_Customer_Model_Form.html#restoreData

in the CustomerController.php:

```
$formData = $customerForm->extractData($request, 'account');
$customerForm->restoreData($formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

var edit_form = varienform(form_id, validationUrl)
Whenever you create a varien form you can pass validation Url and Magento will send Ajax request to this Url before submitting the form and If you get any error, it wont submit the page else will proceed with the submission.

For grid also it uses apply function in grid.js to submit the grid , there you also you can use Ajax to submit grid, check values at server side, throw error/exception- catch at client side-values will be preserved  if there is an error, else submit the grid.